# Embedding of F(4) in OSp(8|4)?

Tags: lie-algebras

Is the superconformal algebra in five dimensions, $F(4)$, a subalgebra of the (maximal) six-dimensional superconformal algebra $OSp(8|4)$?

Comment: Cross-posted to: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/41155/23119

Answer (score 2):

Apparently the answer is "no". For more details see Appeindx C.4.1 of this paper http://arxiv.org/pdf/0810.1484.pdf